# Is there any way to send messgae to someone i connected to his wireless network?

Tags: windows-vista, networking, wireless-networking

I want to send message or something to computer that i connected to it by it's wireless router.

How to do that ?

note:
*I've windows vista 64Bit*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can see the other computer, you may use the [Net Send Command](http://www.lantalk.net/net-send-command/) :

> `net send name_of_user_or_computer message_text`

**EDIT**

In Vista or Windows 7, the "net send" command can be replaced by msg.exe:

> `msg * /server:other-computer "message_text"`

See this article: [MSG.EXE replaces Net Send in Windows Vista](http://www.petri.co.il/msg-exe-net-send-vista.htm).

Comment: that sucks that it doesn't work with vista or windows 7...

Comment: i think its cool as hell though...

Comment: I never tried it in Vista/Win7 so didn't notice it got phased out. See my edit for an alternative.

Comment: I Can't see the other computer. I just can use it's router to connect to inter net. He forgot to set security on his wireless router.

Comment: Once you connect to his network, regard your IP via "ipconfig". If it is something like 192.168.0.X then the router is in 192.168.0.1. You might try to ping him at lower numbers like 192.168.0.2 etc. msg also works with IP addresses.